# Format date field output based on content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I like to theme a date fields output differently on a specific node type (in `template.php` file).

But the problem is that I can't find out in which node type the current function call takes place.

In the hook `THEME_preprocess_node(array &$vars)` I can get the node type with `$vars['node']->type` and compare against this value.

But I'm in the function `THEME_date_display_range(array &$vars)` and there's no node object I could access from that function/hook.

How can I/or can I even get the node type in this function/hook and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that on a node view, you can use menu_get_object function (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) to know which object is loaded by the router

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Although for `menu_` has nothing to do with with the content type of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new template file for your field.

- Copy `field.tpl.php` file located in `modules/field/theme` to your theme folder.
- Rename the file as follows: `field--your-field-name--content-type.tpl.php`.
- Clear the cache, and you are good to go.

Reference: [Drupal 7 template suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656).